# How to maximize a spark.components.Callout? Screenshots attached

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6, callout

How to maximize a [Callout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Callout.html), so that it takes the maximal available space at the screen?

I'm trying [to display a ViewNavigator in a Callout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb706aafb086131b54b6ec7-8000.html#WScc733d9d0dc5f34c146f70711322b1fe177-8000) and while it works, the displayed `View` is too narrow:

[image]

In the same program I have another `Callout` and it is wide enough:

[image]

The only 2 differences between them is that the latter is attached to a [CalloutButton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/CalloutButton.html) and the latter holds a custom `Score` component for which I set:

```
    override protected function measure():void {
        super.measure();
        measuredWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
        measuredHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    }
```

I keep staring at the [Callout.as](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/flex/sdk/branches/develop/frameworks/projects/mobilecomponents/src/spark/components/Callout.as) code, but can't find a way to trick it to occupy most available space yet.

My custom mxml component is quite simple:

**PlayerInfo.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Callout 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    contentBackgroundAppearance="none">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var userid:String;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ViewNavigator 
        firstView="views.Profile"
        firstViewData="{userid}">
        <s:navigationContent>
            <s:Button label="Close" click="close()" />
        </s:navigationContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>

</s:Callout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callout extends Container, so you shouldn't have problems setting the width and height to 100%.

Also, in the Callout code there's a method:

```
/**
 *  @private
 *  Force a new measurement when callout should use it's screen-constrained
 *  max size.
 */
private function invalidateMaxSize():void
{
    // calloutMaxWidth and calloutMaxHeight don't invalidate 
    // explicitMaxWidth or explicitMaxHeight. If callout's max size changes
    // and explicit max sizes aren't set, then invalidate size here so that
    // callout's max size is applied.
    if (!canSkipMeasurement() && !isMaxSizeSet)
        skin.invalidateSize();
}
```

So, try to set the 'explicitMaxWidth' and 'explicitMaxHeight' properties.

Comment: Actually I tried setting `width="100%"` on the `Callout` and/or `ViewNavigator` and this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Adding your workaround for the s:Callout component worked for me (update the PlayerInfo.mxml file): `override protected function measure():void {
super.measure();
measuredWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
measuredHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
}`